# javascript addEventListener and runtime.onMessage.addListener

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm building a Firefox extension using the new webextension standard.

When the user clicks anywhere on the page, I want to put the click in standby for few milliseconds while another function is executing a task in the background script.

Here is part of my code :

**content script:**

```
var CanContinue = false;
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(MsgListener);

function MsgListener(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    if (request.msg == 'can_continue')
        CanContinue = true;
}

function ClickDetected(event)
{
    browser.runtime.sendMessage({"msg": "doWork"});
    while ( ! CanContinue );
}

window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    ClickDetected(event);
}, true);
```

**background script :**

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(MsgListener);

function MsgListener(msg)
{
    if (msg.msg == 'doWork')
    {
        ...
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(TheTabId, {msg: 'can_continue'});  
    }
}
```

The problem is that the content script doesn't receive the `can_continue` message while the click event is pending, so the `while ( ! CanContinue )` never release.

Note that the message is correctly received if I test it out of the click event process.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is single-threaded, and messaging is asynchronous.

`while ( ! CanContinue );` means *all* your code will just hang. The reply is ready, and is sitting in the event queue, but will not be processed until your current code terminates.

You can't "delay" execution this way; you can't "wait" for an asynchronous response.

You could try to work around it by canceling the event and then raising a new one after getting confirmation. I'm not sure if it would work in terms of "user gesture" though.

Comment: Thanks you, I will try this way